# python openpyxl import a data in a cell with a function

Tags: python, import-from-excel, openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb1 = load_workbook(filename = 'B.xlsx')
sheet_ranges1 = wb1["Sheet1"]
wb1.save('B.xlsx')

print (sheet_ranges1.cell(row=10,column=8).internal_value)
```

I want to load data from **.xlsx** file. The **sheet_ranges1.cell(ro=10,column=8)** is same as **sheet_ranges1.cell('H10')**. And in the EXCEL file, the **H10** is a **SUM** function. When I print it in python:

```
print (sheet_ranges1.cell(row=10,column=8).internal_value)
```

It shows:

```
=SUM(N23:N128)
```

I want to know how to  show the number in H10. It seems that **.internal_value** and **.value** both can't work. I also tried `data_only=True`, but it seems not work.

For example:

```
     A     B     C
1    4     5     9
```

C1=A1+B1

```
wb1 = load_workbook(filename = 'B.xlsx')
sheet_ranges1 = wb1["Sheet1"]
wb1.save('B.xlsx')

print (sheet_ranges1.cell(row=2,column=3).value)
```

**result: 'A1+B1'**

```
wb1 = load_workbook(filename = 'B.xlsx',data_only=True)
sheet_ranges1 = wb1["Sheet1"]
wb1.save('B.xlsx')

print (sheet_ranges1.cell(row=2,column=3).value)
```

**results:9**

I want to use `openpyxl` change the value of **A1** and **B1**, and import C1 in to another excel file. However, if I don't use `data_only=True` the result will be '=A1+B1'. If I use `data_only=True`, after I change the value **A1,B1** to 5,6, **C1**=9, namely the function doesn't exist in **C1** cell.

> Blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Openpyxl is designed like this and you can retrieve the value of a formula or the formula but never both. The reason for this is that openpyxl never evaluates formulae and as such can never guarantee validity of result. Excel stores the last calulated value of a formula, which we can read. But, we assume that you may make changes to the values used in a formula, which would invalidate this and required the formula to be recalculated. If you want to do this, you must pass the file to an application which can do this.